# Regex to match words with condition

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like this

```
var msg = "ATEAM-3121 ATEAM-31 123 ATEAM-32 #finish \n ATEAM-3211 \n ATEAM-51 ATEAM-52 ATEAM-53 12345677 #finish ATEAM-1000";
```

In above string, for each line, I would like to match tags matching ATEAM-[0-9]* before #finish tag. If any line does not have #finish, all ATEAM tags should be ignored.

Here is the non regex solution that works

```
msg = msg.split("\n");
var tickets = [];
msg.forEach(function(val) {
  var ticks = val.split(' ');
  for(var i = ticks.indexOf('#finish'); i >= 0; i-- ) {
    if(ticks[i].match(/^ATEAM-.*$/)) {
      tickets.push(ticks[i]);
    }
  }
});
console.log(tickets);
```

But would like to convert it to Regex solution and this is what I have tried

```
msg.match(/(ATEAM-[0-9]*|\#finish)/g);
```

But it gives me result like in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hm513hd6/3/), but its not as expected. Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ATEAM-[0-9]+(?=.*?#finish)
```

You can do this using `lookahead`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/uF4oY4/88

Comment: This is what I am looking for. Thanks

Comment: I am waiting for the 10 minutes to be completed to accept. At the time I checked it was 54 seconds remaining :)